Obtener registros por la fecha mas reciente de consulta agrupada Laravel
necesito una ayuda me he trancado un poco, tengo una consulta en laravel la cual hace un leftjoin con otra tabla y quiero obtener de ella los registros con la fecha mas reciente de peso lo cual esta denotado con el  campo fulpes Acá muestro el Json de la consulta:
"2392": [
  {
    "id": 8946,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "35369",
    "tipo": "VACA VACIA",
    "pesodestete": 140,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2015-05-11",
    "caso": "PARTO",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": "Salida por Venta y Comercialización",
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2018-02-18",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-26 09:52:41"
  },
  {
    "id": 9169,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "3732",
    "tipo": "BECERRO",
    "pesodestete": null,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2017-02-27",
    "caso": "PARTO",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": null,
    "updated_at": "2019-08-09 17:21:30"
  },
  {
    "id": 9369,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "38261",
    "tipo": "MAUTE",
    "pesodestete": 195,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2018-05-10",
    "caso": "PARTO",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2018-12-05",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-28 17:23:32"
  },
  {
    "id": 9868,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "39117",
    "tipo": "MAUTE",
    "pesodestete": 178,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2020-04-06",
    "caso": "PARTO",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2021-01-21",
    "updated_at": "2021-02-09 17:23:32"
  },
  {
    "id": 8946,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "35369",
    "tipo": "MAUTA",
    "pesodestete": 140,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2015-05-11",
    "caso": "PARTO",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2016-09-15",
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 9169,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "3732",
    "tipo": "MAUTE",
    "pesodestete": 190,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2017-02-27",
    "caso": "PARTO",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2019-02-01",
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 9369,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "38261",
    "tipo": "TORETE",
    "pesodestete": 195,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2018-05-10",
    "caso": "PARTO",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2021-01-06",
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 9868,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "39117",
    "tipo": "TORO",
    "pesodestete": 147,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2020-04-06",
    "caso": "PARTO",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": "Venta",
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2023-09-23",
    "updated_at": "2023-09-25 08:28:45"
  },
  {
    "id": 11621,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "40112",
    "tipo": "MAUTE",
    "pesodestete": 180,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2022-03-08",
    "caso": "Parto",
    "serieh": "40112",
    "iee": 0,
    "ientpar": 0,
    "motivo": "Transferencia de una Finca a Otra",
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2023-02-08",
    "updated_at": "2023-02-16 10:02:58"
  },
  {
    "id": 11621,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "40112",
    "tipo": "TORETE",
    "pesodestete": 180,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2022-03-08",
    "caso": "Parto",
    "serieh": "40112",
    "iee": 0,
    "ientpar": 0,
    "motivo": "Transferencia de una Finca a Otra",
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2024-03-19",
    "updated_at": "2024-03-19 15:39:08"
  },
  {
    "id": 12694,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "41186",
    "tipo": "MAUTE",
    "pesodestete": 176,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2023-03-16",
    "caso": "Parto",
    "serieh": "41186",
    "iee": 279,
    "ientpar": 369,
    "motivo": "Transferencia de una Finca a Otra",
    "status": 0,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2023-10-04",
    "updated_at": "2024-01-26 14:54:12"
  },
  {
    "id": 12694,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "41186",
    "tipo": "MAUTE",
    "pesodestete": 176,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2023-03-16",
    "caso": "Parto",
    "serieh": "41186",
    "iee": 279,
    "ientpar": 369,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": 1,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2023-10-04",
    "updated_at": "2024-06-28 09:15:10"
  },
  {
    "id": 11621,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "40112",
    "tipo": "TORETE",
    "pesodestete": 180,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2022-03-08",
    "caso": "Parto",
    "serieh": "40112",
    "iee": 0,
    "ientpar": 0,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": 1,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2024-06-21",
    "updated_at": "2024-06-26 11:21:49"
  },
  {
    "id": 13932,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": "42278",
    "tipo": "BECERRA",
    "pesodestete": null,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2024-03-25",
    "caso": "Parto",
    "serieh": "42278",
    "iee": 266,
    "ientpar": 221,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": 1,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": "2024-03-25",
    "updated_at": "2024-04-05 08:45:18"
  },
  {
    "id": 855,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": null,
    "tipo": null,
    "pesodestete": null,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": "2017-05-09",
    "caso": "NAC.MUE",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": null,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 11013,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": null,
    "tipo": null,
    "pesodestete": null,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": null,
    "caso": "PREÑ",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": null,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 12367,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": null,
    "tipo": null,
    "pesodestete": null,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": null,
    "caso": "PREÑ",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": null,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 13162,
    "id_serie": 3836,
    "codmadre": "2392",
    "serie_hijo": null,
    "tipo": null,
    "pesodestete": null,
    "codpadre": null,
    "pajuela": null,
    "fecha": null,
    "caso": "PREÑ",
    "serieh": null,
    "iee": null,
    "ientpar": null,
    "motivo": null,
    "status": null,
    "id_finca": 1,
    "fulpes": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
]
}

En mi controlador
$vientresDatosVida = DB::table('sgmv1s')
        ->select('sgmv1s.id','sgmv1s.id_serie','sgmv1s.codmadre','sgmv1s.serie_hijo','sganims.tipo','sganims.pesodestete','sgmv1s.codpadre','sgmv1s.pajuela','sgmv1s.fecha','sgmv1s.caso','sgdatosvidas.serieh','sgdatosvidas.iee','sgdatosvidas.ientpar','sganims.motivo', 'sganims.status','sgmv1s.id_finca','sganims.fulpes','sganims.updated_at')
        
        ->where('sgmv1s.id_finca',$id_finca)
        
        ->leftjoin('sgdatosvidas','sgmv1s.serie_hijo','=','sgdatosvidas.serieh')
        ->leftjoin('sganims','sgmv1s.serie_hijo','=','sganims.serie')
        ->where([
                ['sgmv1s.id_finca','=',$id_finca],
               # ['sganims.id_finca','=',$id_finca],
                ])
        ->whereIn('sgmv1s.id_serie',$codMadres)
        ->get()->groupBy('codmadre');    

Si se observamos un poco para el codmadre:2392 tiene en el indice 1 y 5 serie_hijo: 3732, quiero mostrar de ellos el que tiene la fecha fulpes mas reciente y asi sucesivamente para el restro de los registros. Espero haberme explicado bien. Un Gran Saludos.
